# Why does YouTube add a space at the end of title edits?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, user-behavior

I've noticed this behaviour on YouTube when editing the titles of videos I've uploaded:

[image: YouTube title edit bar]

In the screenshot above, YouTube has automatically added a space character after the title. If YouTube have gone to the trouble of adding this feature, I'm guessing that they must feel that it adds something to the user interaction.

What purpose does this additional space serve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With this feature, if a user leaves the title field and then clicks on it again to continue typing, they don't have to type "space" first before adding another word.